# generating table that indicates position of nth 1 bit in a byte at compile time

Tags: arrays, c++11, compile-time

I am trying to figure out how to generate an array of precomputed values at compile time in C++ (C++11).

The array is declared as `unsigned char precalcalated_positions[256][8]`, and for `precalcalated_positions[x][y]` gives the bit position (0-7) of the y+1'th 1 bit counting from the right in the byte value x or the number 8 if there are not that many 1 bits in x

So for example the array entry `precalculated_positions[51][2]` would be 4 since 51 = 00110011 in binary and since the 3rd (2+1) 1 bit from the right equals 1<<4.

While I could fairly easily write a program to generate the source code for this array,  I am wondering if it is possible for the compiler itself to generate this array at compile time perhaps by using some clever template metaprogramming and perhaps some constexpr functions?

Code that produces the table at runtime (not optimized) follows:

```
int calculate_index(unsigned char c,unsigned char pos)
{
    int mask = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        if (c&mask) {
            if (pos==0) {
                return i;
            } else {
                pos--;
            }
        }
        mask<<=1;
    }
    return 8;
}
void generate_table() {
   for(int i=0;i<256;i++) for(int j=0;j<8;j++) {
      precalulated_positions[i][j] = calculate_index(i,j);
   }
}
```

While any help is sincerely appreciated, please note that this is for C++11 only.   For my purposes, I cannot use constructs that are new to C++14.

If anything is unclear, please ask and I will try to elaborate further as necessary.

Comment: Have you actually tried writing the code that does it at runtime ? If so, posting it might get more people to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.   I've added code that generates the table at runtime.

Comment: Any chance you can use c++14? If so then I think you can just mark these functions constexpr and call it a day.

Comment: No.... unfortunately I cannot.   But even if the function `calculate_index` were made constexpr (which it probably can be, even for C++11, I just haven't worked out how yet), that still wouldn't generate the table at compile time, and I would still have to call that function.  I can call `generate_table` once at runtime, of course, and just use the array after that, but I'd like to know if it's possible for the compiler to generate that array for me.

Comment: As it turns out, coming up with a C++11 solution to that problem was quite a bit challenging, but interesting nonetheless !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I didn't realize you couldn't use C++14. I came up with another solution using C++11 only. I left the C++14 code below.

I transformed your algorithm into a recursive version (to fit in a constexpr function), and used template parameter packs to fill the table.

```
template<int... Is>
struct Seq {};
template<int N, int... Is>
struct Gen : Gen<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is>
struct Gen<0, Is...> : Seq<Is...> {};

constexpr auto computePosition(int c, int bit, int pos = 0) -> unsigned char {
    return pos == 8 ?
        8 :
        (c & (1 << pos)) == 0 ?
            computePosition(c, bit, pos+1) :
            bit == 0 ?
                pos :
                computePosition(c, bit-1, pos+1);
}

template<int c, int... Is>
constexpr auto generatePositions(Seq<Is...>) -> std::array<unsigned char, 8> {
    return {{ computePosition(c, Is)... }};
}

template<int c>
constexpr auto generatePositions() -> std::array<unsigned char, 8> {
    return generatePositions<c>(Gen<8>{});
}

template<int... Is>
constexpr auto generateTable(Seq<Is...>) -> std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 8>, 256> {
    return {{ generatePositions<Is>()... }};
}

constexpr auto generateTable() -> std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 8>, 256> {
    return generateTable(Gen<256>{});
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d7b8dcfe310caee)

A C++14 version :

```
struct Table {
    constexpr Table() : positions() {
        for (auto c = 0; c < 256; ++c) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                int mask = 1;
                auto pos = -1;
                auto bit = i;
                while (pos < 8 && bit >= 0) {
                    if (c & mask) {
                        --bit;
                    }
                    ++pos;
                    mask <<= 1;
                }
                positions[c][i] = pos;
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned char positions[256][8];
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto precalculated_positions = Table();
    static_assert(precalculated_positions.positions[51][2] == 4, "wrong");
}
```

The values are in the `positions` field of any variable of type `Table`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caf50c6434e7de5f)